# Does the connexity property imply the reflexive property?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

I know that a partial order may or may not be a total order. In fact, a total order is a subset of a partial order. But I was thinking about:

Does total order $\implies$ partial order?

In a total order, we have the connexity property ($a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$) (I am considering  $\leq$ as $R$ ($aRb$ or $bRa$)). In a partial order, we have reflexivity instead of the connexity of a total order.

If $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$, then is it true that the reflexive property holds? I am confused here.

Say $a \leq b$. Then $b$ need not be $\leq a$ right? The reflexive property does not hold?

Comment: Yes, you particularize the property $\forall a\forall b (a\leq b \vee b\leq a)$ to the case $a=b$ to get $\forall a(a\leq a \vee a\leq a)$, which is equivalent to $\forall a(a\leq a)$.

Comment: Ok. So total order is always partial order but converse need not be true right? Please correct me if i am wrong  [(P(S), subset) is partial order but not total order]

Comment: That's right. In total orders all elements are related, but in partial orders that needs not be true. The example $[P(S), \subset]$ is a non-total partial order for $|S|\geq 2$.

Comment: thank you........

Comment: @conditionalMethod I think you should post your first comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to their profile, user "conditionalMethod" was last seen on Mathematics Stack Exchange more than two years ago. Therefore, I am posting that user's answer in comments as a community wiki answer:

Yes, you particularize the property $\forall a\forall b (a\leq b \vee b\leq a)$ to the case $a = b$ to get $\forall a(a\leq a \vee a\leq a)$, which is equivalent to $\forall a(a\leq a)$.